# Mean +ing or mean +infinitive with to

Tags: meaning-in-context, gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive

Can anyone explain the difference between "mean +ing" and "mean +infinitive with to"?
As far as I know one uses "mean +infinitive with to" to show one`s intentions and "mean +ing" to express what will be the result of some actions. Am I right?

For example what should we put into blanks over here :

> I meant **to tell/telling** you there`s a job vacancy at the chemist's.
>
> Well, I won't apply if it means **to work/working** at the weekend.

Comment: can you give some examples?

Comment: @ChrisM, done. Examples are added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

> 'I meant to tell you there's a job vacancy'

and

> 'I won't apply if it means working at the weekend'

> I mean to ...

Conveys having the intention of doing something

> It means doing ...

Is an idiom signifying "will result in" ....

Comment: @Yaroslav Trofimov No worries!